# Calling Collection.allow() manually to check permissions

Tags: permissions, meteor

In Meteor JS I want to perform a task before adding an object to my collection. So I created my own method, eg: `addObject` like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
    ...
    addObject: function(obj) {
        /*
        // this is what i'm trying to figure out...
        if ( !MyColl.allow('insert', Meteor.userId, obj) )
            throw Meteor.Error(403, 'Sorry');
        */

        MyColl.update({ ... }}, { 'multi': true });
        MyColl.insert(obj);
    },
    ...
});
```

But I noticed that .allow is no longer being called because it's "trusted" code. The thing is the method is on the server but being called from the client (through ObjectiveDDP) so I still need a way to validate that the client has permissions to call `addObject` - is there any way to manually call `.allow()` on a collection from my server code? I tried it but getting an internal server error, and not sure what the syntax should be... couldn't find anything in the Meteor docs.

**Edit:**

I just found out that this works:

```
var allowedToInsert = MyColl._validators.insert.allow[0];
if (!allowedToInsert)
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Invalid permissions.');
```

But that's probably a no-no calling private methods such as _validators. Does anyone know of a more 'best practices' way?

Comment: Take note that as Meteor is still in beta, accessing private elements is often the best way to achieve your goal. The main downside is that those may stop working after version upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation in the addobject method. For example, if you only want logged in users to be able to add an object, you can write:
if (!Meteor.user()) throw new Meteor.Error();
at the beginning of the addobject method.

Personally I never use allow.

On a related note, the collection2 and simple-schema packages can often help a lot with validation.

Answer (score 0):

The validation pattern you are using might not be the best way to do things.

If you assume that methods can be called from the client, you shouldn't 'hack' it into doing something it's not meant to do.

If you are calling a method that changes data in the database you should check within that method that the currently logged in user has permission to do so.

However, are you sure you want to do this? Meteor also has `Collection.allow` and `Collection.deny` methods that you can use to define read/write/update/delete permission with. That's the recommended way to handle permissions, so what you are doing is an anti-pattern. However, perhaps in your case it is strictly necessary? If not, you might want to rethink the use case.

Like another response suggests, using something like `Collections` or `SimpleSchema` to validate data structure is also a good idea.